# Rails app - working fine locally but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am building a simple app in Rails, everything has been working fine so far but now, after not working on it for a while, I cannot run the app in Heroku. Here are the errors I have on my logs. I would appreciate if someone could help me with these problem.

```
> 2016-01-07T10:25:13.640157+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by chmorasan@gmail.com
> heroku[run.9775]: Awaiting client heroku[run.9775]: State changed from
> starting to up heroku[run.9775]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to
> a heroku[run.9775]: Process exited with status 128 heroku[run.9775]:
> State changed from up to complete heroku[run.1708]: State changed from
> starting to up

2016-01-07T09:08:52.323403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=thecornershop.herokuapp.com request_id=469ee49d-d3a5-40bb-a6a7-f50efbfb89ef fwd="194.224.214.178" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-07T09:08:52.788969+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thecornershop.herokuapp.com request_id=cf2a50ed-2ef8-440a-8bc4-15be5f1f2244 fwd="194.224.214.178" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-07T09:22:41.171885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=thecornershop.herokuapp.com request_id=ba18bf52-9740-4e4e-b5bb-1f54dd40acb1 fwd="194.224.214.178" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-07T09:22:41.699518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thecornershop.herokuapp.com request_id=babe9b0d-e6f5-4e0f-8d76-35a7217165eb fwd="194.224.214.178" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I finally found the problem, it was somethings that I forgot to erase in a earlier mistake I did migrating, I just forgot to look in the actual db migrate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post complete line which says: `> heroku[api]: Starting process with command 'bundle exec r` Looks like it is not completely pasted there

Comment: I have update the line now

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that which command you are trying to run on heroku, however, your log says:

> heroku[run.9775]: Awaiting client heroku[run.9775]: State changed from starting to up heroku[run.9775]: **Error R13 (Attach error)**

Try to detach your command from terminal. Run it in the "background"

```
heroku run:detached <YOUR_COMMAND>
```

**EDIT:**

As you are trying to `migrate` your migration files:

```
heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Unfortunately is not working for me. Is still giving me the same error again.

Comment: heroku run:detached rake db:migrate`